# Getting write access to the home directory in node.js on heroku to resolve ResumableUploadError

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-storage

In my node app, I am using the google cloud storage to upload large files to google cloud storage making use of the following npm package:

```
  "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.3.4",
```

For larger file uploads, the google documentation recommends a composite object/parallel upload strategy which basically involves taking the larger and breaking it into smaller chunks to be sent across the wire.  More about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects) .

Now when I deploy my application to heroku, this packages needs to write to a directory it creates inside my home directory at the following location.

```
/app/.config
```

By default it would appear that heroku does not allow write access to the file system so I get the following error when attempting to upload:

```
     ResumableUploadError: A resumable upload could not be performed. 
    The directory, /app/.config, is not writable. 
You may try another upload, this time setting `options.resumable` to `false`
```

Since this resumable flag gets set to false it causes my uploads to timeout.  Is there anything I can do to get write access to the file system to this directory so this doesn't happen?  Thanks for your help in advance!

Here is additional info from the docs about the method createWriteStream that I am using for this [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#createResumableUpload).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a folder named .config in the root solved my issue, i had the same error as yours (.config is not writable)

```
mkdir .config
```